# upload a directory to s3 with boto

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto

I am already connected to the instance and I want to upload the files that are generated from my python script directly to S3. I have tried this:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('alexandrabucket')
from boto.s3.key import Key
key = bucket.new_key('s0').set_contents_from_string('some content')
```

but this is rather creating a new file s0 with the context "same content" while I want to upload the directory s0 to mybucket.

I had a look also to s3put but I didn't manage to get what I want.

Comment: May be you might want to have a look at this, looks like a [somewhat similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317243/boto-uploading-file-to-a-specific-location-on-amazon-s3?rq=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is nothing in the `boto` library itself that would allow you to upload an entire directory.  You could write your own code to traverse the directory using `os.walk` or similar and to upload each individual file using boto.

There is a command line utility in boto called `s3put` that could handle this or you could use the [AWS CLI tool](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) which has a lot of features that allow you to upload entire directories or even sync the S3 bucket with a local directory or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks `s3 sync` looks like it does the job http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Uploading each file at a time using `os.walk` is much much slower than uploading in a batch..

Comment: Still no function in boto3 to upload a folder directly?

Answer (score 45):

The following function can be used to upload directory to s3 via boto.

```
    def uploadDirectory(path,bucketname):
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                s3C.upload_file(os.path.join(root,file),bucketname,file)
```

Provide a path to the directory and bucket name as the inputs. The files are placed directly into the bucket. Alter the last variable of the upload_file() function to place them in "directories".

Comment: What is this s3 object? Is it the Boto client? I can't see anything that exposes upload_file

Comment: @serlingpa yes it is a the boto3 client, it is instantiated like this: s3C = boto3.client('s3')

Comment: Better solution here https://gist.github.com/feelinc/d1f541af4f31d09a2ec3

Answer (score 11):

The [s3fs package](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides nice functionalities to handle such cases

```
s3_file = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
local_path = "some_dir_path/some_dir_path/"
s3_path = "bucket_name/dir_path"
s3_file.put(local_path, s3_path, recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I built the function based on the feedback from @JDPTET, however,

1. I needed to remove the common entire local path from getting uploaded to the bucket!
2. Not sure how many path separators I encounter - so I had to use `os.path.normpath`

```
    def upload_folder_to_s3(s3bucket, inputDir, s3Path):
        print("Uploading results to s3 initiated...")
        print("Local Source:",inputDir)
        os.system("ls -ltR " + inputDir)

        print("Dest  S3path:",s3Path)

        try:
            for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
                for file in files:
                    dest_path = path.replace(inputDir,"")
                    __s3file = os.path.normpath(s3Path + '/' + dest_path + '/' + file)
                    __local_file = os.path.join(path, file)
                    print("upload : ", __local_file, " to Target: ", __s3file, end="")
                    s3bucket.upload_file(__local_file, __s3file)
                    print(" ...Success")
        except Exception as e:
            print(" ... Failed!! Quitting Upload!!")
            print(e)
            raise e

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
    s3bucket = s3.Bucket("<<s3bucket_name>>")
    upload_folder_to_s3(s3bucket, "<<Local Folder>>", "<<s3 Path>>")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
import os
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")

def upload_objects():
    try:
        bucket_name = "S3_Bucket_Name" #s3 bucket name
        root_path = 'D:/sample/' # local folder for upload

        my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)

        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
            path = path.replace("\\","/")
            directory_name = path.replace(root_path,"")
            for file in files:
                my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file), directory_name+'/'+file)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload_objects()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the replace calls in the `path` and `directory_name` are for, but overall this was useful!

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I used which recursively upload files from the specified folder to the specified s3 path. Just add S3 credential and bucket details in the script:

https://gist.github.com/hari116/4ab5ebd885b63e699c4662cd8382c314/

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Usage: Add bucket name and credentials
          script.py <source folder> <s3 destination folder >"""

import os
from sys import argv
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

ACCESS_KEY = ''
SECRET_KEY = ''
host = ''
bucket_name = ''

local_folder, s3_folder = argv[1:3]
walks = os.walk(local_folder)
# Function to upload to s3
def upload_to_aws(bucket, local_file, s3_file):
    """local_file, s3_file can be paths"""
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    print('  Uploading ' +local_file + ' as ' + bucket + '/' +s3_file)
    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print('  '+s3_file + ": Upload Successful")
        print('  ---------')
        return True
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False

"""For file names"""
for source, dirs, files in walks:
    print('Directory: ' + source)
    for filename in files:
        # construct the full local path
        local_file = os.path.join(source, filename)
        # construct the full Dropbox path
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_file, local_folder)
        s3_file = os.path.join(s3_folder, relative_path)
        # Invoke upload function
        upload_to_aws(bucket_name, local_file, s3_file)
```

Answer (score 3):

Somehow the other snippets did not really work for me, this is a modification of the snippet from user 923227 that does.

This code copies all files in a directory and maintains the directory in S3, e.g.`2023/01/file.jpg` will be in the bucket as `2023/01/file.jpg`.

```
import os
import sys
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
local_path = "your-path/data"
bucketname = "bucket-name"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(local_path):
    for file in files:
        file_s3 = os.path.normpath(path + '/' + file)
        file_local = os.path.join(path, file)
        print("Upload:", file_local, "to target:", file_s3, end="")
        client.upload_file(file_local, bucketname, file_s3)
        print(" ...Success")
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated @user 923227's answer to (1) include newer boto3 interface (2) work with nuances of windows double backslash (3) cleaner tqdm progress bar:

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

def upload_folder_to_s3(s3_client, s3bucket, input_dir, s3_path):
    pbar = tqdm(os.walk(input_dir))
    for path, subdirs, files in pbar:
        for file in files:
            dest_path = path.replace(input_dir, "").replace(os.sep, '/')
            s3_file = f'{s3_path}/{dest_path}/{file}'.replace('//', '/')
            local_file = os.path.join(path, file)
            s3_client.upload_file(local_file, s3bucket, s3_file)
            pbar.set_description(f'Uploaded {local_file} to {s3_file}')
    print(f"Successfully uploaded {input_dir} to S3 {s3_path}")
```

Usage example:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
upload_folder_to_s3(s3_client, 'BUCKET-NAME', <local-directory>, <s3-directory>)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reading file form folder we can use

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

keyId = 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
sKeyId='YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
bucketName='your_bucket_name'

conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,sKeyId)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
for key in bucket.list():
    print ">>>>>"+key.name
    pathV = key.name.split('/')
    if(pathV[0] == "data"):
        if(pathV[1] != ""):
            srcFileName = key.name
            filename = key.name
            filename = filename.split('/')[1]
            destFileName = "model/data/"+filename
            k = Key(bucket,srcFileName)
            k.get_contents_to_filename(destFileName)
    elif(pathV[0] == "nlu_data"):
        if(pathV[1] != ""):
            srcFileName = key.name
            filename = key.name
            filename = filename.split('/')[1]
            destFileName = "model/nlu_data/"+filename
            k = Key(bucket,srcFileName)
            k.get_contents_to_filename(destFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method that did not exist when this question was first asked is to use python-rclone (https://github.com/ddragosd/python-rclone/blob/master/README.md).

This requires a download of rclone and a working rclone config. Commonly used for AWS (https://rclone.org/s3/) but can be used for other providers as well.

```
install('python-rclone')
import rclone
cfg_path = r'(path to rclone config file here)'

with open(cfg_path) as f:
   cfg = f.read()

# Implementation
# Local file to cloud server
result = rclone.with_config(cfg).run_cmd(command="sync", extra_args=["/home/demodir/", "AWS test:dummydir/etc/"])
# Cloud server to cloud server
result = rclone.with_config(cfg).run_cmd(command="sync", extra_args=["Gdrive:test/testing/", "AWS test:dummydir/etc/"
```

This allows you to run a "sync" command similar to the AWS CLI within your python code by reading in the config file and mapping your output via kwargs (extra_args)

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use boto, but I think it could do what the OP wants.

It uses awscli and Python.

```py
import os

class AwsCredentials:
    def __init__(self, access_key: str, secret_key: str):
        self.access_key = access_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    def to_command(self):
        credentials = f'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={self.access_key} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={self.secret_key}'
        return credentials


def sync_s3_bucket(credentials: AwsCredentials, source_path: str, bucket: str) -> None:
    command = f'{credentials.to_command()} aws s3 sync {source_path} s3://{bucket}'
    result = os.system(command)
    assert result == 0, f'The s3 sync was not successful, error code: {result}'
```

Please consider getting the AWS credentials from a file or from the environment.

The documentation for the `s3 sync` command is [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simply running terminal commands using os module with F string works

```
import os
ActualFolderName = "FolderToBeUploadedOnS3"
os.system(f'aws s3 cp D:\<PathToYourFolder>\{ActualFolderName} s3://<BucketName>/{ActualFolderName}/ --recursive')
```

Comment: While this might work, it looks like this answer does not use boto, as was specified inthe question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using `pathlib` instead:

```py
import boto3
from pathlib import Path

def upload_directory_to_s3(directory: str) -> None:
    for path in Path(directory).rglob('*'):
        if path.is_file():
            boto3.client('s3').upload_file(file_name=path, bucket=bucket, object_name=f'{key}/{path}')
```