# Unable to upload image to amazon s3 from boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I need to upload images to Amazon S3 bucket,I have the AWS_KEY,AWS_SECRET and Bucket name.
Please find the code below to upload the images to aws s3.When i try to upload getting, the following error...

```
AWS_KEY = "xxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET = "xxxxxx"

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

filenames = ['D:/Share/1_test.png']
conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
for fname in filenames:
    print fname 
    bucket = conn.get_bucket("xxxxxxx",validate = False)
    print bucket 
    #key = bucket.new_key(fname).set_contents_from_string('test img')
    key = Key(bucket)
    key.key = fname
    key.set_contents_from_filename(fname)
    print "uploaded file %s" % fname
```

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request 
>   `InvalidRequest`The authorization mechanism
>   you have provided is not supported.  Please use
>   AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.0E67564A45D10F51UCh6NhAz2x75gW17D4pMNxPepLn7q3ISXZzzucA+bd/oDRC+rSv8nlnGB/ejgUsGaofDu1rLy9g=

Comment: Which line is raising this error?

Comment: May be here key = Key(bucket), key.key = fname,,key.set_contents_from_filename(fname) i  thiink.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085864/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-s3-bucket-using-boto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317243/boto-uploading-file-to-a-specific-location-on-amazon-s3